# Need to find out how many 5 Stars I need

Tags: calculus

I am looking for a formula to figure out how many more 5 star ratings I need in order to create a 5 Star rating...and I need your help. I am using a weighted average to determine a Star rating from one to 5.
Here is my formula: 
(5*Q1+4*Q2+3*Q3+2*Q4+1*Q5)/(Q1+Q2+Q3+Q4+Q5) where the Q's are the current amount for each Star rating
What I need now is a way (formula) to figure out how many more 5 star reviews that are needed to bring the overall star rating to a 5 (highest rating).
Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks
Robert

Comment: Unless all of the ratings are "5 star" ratings, then the average will always be less than a "5 star" rating.  Which either means that the answer is "infinitely many" or you have left out some information about when to round up to five (I suppose we could assume that 4.5 rounds up to 5, but maybe you want to be more liberal or conservative with your ratings... *shrugs*).

Comment: I second what @XanderHenderson said and I add: the current weighting formula makes no sense at all. Suppose you have $2$ 2-stars, $2$ 4-stars and $12$ 5-stars. Then you formula gives a weighted rating of $1.5$. Given that $75\%$ of the ratings are 5-stars it really seems of dubious usefulness.

Comment: I am trying to use the above formula to help local businesses understand their Google rating. The formula that I posted was one that I found online. It seems to work well. Here is what I've crafted so far. http://clarity.outgrow.us/HowManyReviewsDoYouNeed For the second part I wanted to show how many 5 stars they need to generate a 5 Star rating. Do you have a better way to set this up. And how would I go about determining how many 5 stars I need? Thanks

Comment: @RobertHouston i suggest you are making some ceiling function because average of stars can never be 5 when atleast one <5 star is non nil. How do you round numbers i mean after how many suffix 0's ?